# Manual merge only on Git Extensions

Tags: git, merge, git-pull, git-extensions

I am very new to Git, and I use Git extensions. Whenever I pull, Git auto merges using [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and only requests help when it sees conflicts. However, I am not very satisfied with the auto merge feature as I see the merged files had a few conflicts which were not reported. I would like to disable auto merge in Git Extensions. I would like Git to give me the control to manually merge the files every time I pull.

As I am very new to Git, if you ask me to change a few .git files, please do mention the most probable physical location of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

```
* -merge
```

That would "`unset`" the automatic merge.

You have a choice of:

- committing that file (everybody cloning your repo will have to deal with manual merges)
- or putting that directive in a `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file (local only to your repo)

Note that the `kdiff3` can be changed by the `merge.tool` config.