# Git extensions no longer automatically merges on pull

Tags: git-pull, git-extensions

This is essentially the opposite issue as [Manual Merge Only on GIT extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478365/manual-merge-only-on-git-extensions).

Git extensions used to automatically merge for me when necessary on each pull. For some reason now it doesn't, and I have to use the Git Bash to pull there manually (and in that instance it will automatically merge).

What's going on? I don't see a .gitattributes file in the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Pull dialog, there are three radio buttons for setting the merge options. Did you check them?
Once I accidentally set this to `Do not merge`, maybe that's your problem, too.